# Hadoop Yarn Fair Scheduler with Parent-Child Jobs : Jobs are starving due to deadlock

Tags: hadoop, deadlock, oozie, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

**Problem statement and Question :**

(In the context of hadoop and jobs which can fork child jobs) Oozie launcher jobs will be RUNNING till the completion of child jobs. When too many jobs are scheduled, the child jobs will not be able to run as all of the resources are allocated to parent jobs. Parent jobs cant release resources till child jobs finish and Child cant run till they get resources -- a typical deadlock. What is efficient way to avoid these deadlocks ? (efficient way = best possible resource allocation)

**Background**

On `Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.3.0` cluster configured with YARN and its `Fair scheduler`, I use Oozie to schedule jobs. I understand and account one extra launcher job(= a Map Task in a Container managed by its own Application Master) for resource allocations.

**Current solutions and the problems associated** :

1. Pre-calculate total maximum resources required to comfortably run a job and then using this value to limit maximum number of jobs to be allowed to run simultaneously.

   *Problems :*

   - Under utilization of resources as the resources are reserved in advance.
   - Problems with scaling up and down of cluster size. Lets say a node dies or I add new node, then I have to update this settings(I think this is not the hadoop way of managing cluster)
2. Separate oozie launcher(parent) jobs from child jobs by putting them into different job queues, say "oozie_pool" and "default_pool". In fair scheduler config, I gave an appropriate weights to each queues(oozie_pool=10%; default_pool=90%).

   *Problem:*

   - at this time 'fair schedular' is not robust. In my setup, it occasionally stops pre-emptying. One cause is it runs into infinite polling loop when a task requests 'X' units of memory but no single node alone has 'X' units free memory while the *sum of available memory* units in all nodes is greater than 'X'.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I have the same problem, soon or later I meet deadlock problem.

Comment: Not fixed. I am relying on workaround 1(mentioned in question as solution 1). My only hope is to upgrade to hadoop-2.6 and benchmark again